# C# Global Namespace Alias (class TestClass : global::TestApp)

Tags: c#

I was looking at this page [MSDN: Global namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx).

They have the following piece of code there.

```
class TestApp
{
    // Define a new class called 'System' to cause problems. 
    public class System { }

    // Define a constant called 'Console' to cause more problems. 
    const int Console = 7;
    const int number = 66;

    static void Main()
    {
        // The following line causes an error. It accesses TestApp.Console, 
        // which is a constant. 
        //Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

The they give further examples.

I understand how `global` is used here:

```
// OK
global::System.Console.WriteLine(number);
```

However, I do not understand what the following does (especially how `global::TestApp` and `:` are used on same line):

```
class TestClass : global::TestApp
```

The MSDN page says about the above code: "**the following declaration is referencing TestApp as a member of the global space."**.

Could someone explain this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is strong-naming for a class TestApp that exists at the global level, similar to System. If you were to say `class TestClass : global::System.Console` you would be inheriting the global system console (if that were legal). So in this example you are inheriting the TestApp that is defined at global scope.

So for additional clarity, consider this the following namespace model for things:

```
namespace global
{
    // all things are within this namespace, and therefor
    // it is typically deduced by the compiler. only during
    // name collisions does it require being explicity
    // strong named

    public class TestApp
    {
    }

    namespace Program1
    {
        public class TestClass : global::TestApp
        {
            // notice how this relates to the outermost namespace 'global'
            // as if it were a traditional namespace.
            // the reason this seems strange is because we traditionally
            // develop at a more inner level namespace, such as Program1.

        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this example will better illustrate it:

**Code:**

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClass1 = new MyClass();
            var myClass2 = new global::MyClass();
        }

        public class MyClass { }
    }
}

public class MyClass { }
```

**Explanation:**

`myClass1` is an instance of the class in the `Test` namespace

`myClass2` is an instance of the class in the `global` namespace, aka no namespace.

`global::` can be used to access items that are hidden by locally defined objects.  In this case, `Test.MyClass` hides access to `global::MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

The `global` is used the same way in both:

```
    global::System.Console.WriteLine(number);
```

is to

```
    System.Console.WriteLine(number);
```

as

```
    class TestClass : global::TestApp
```

is to

```
    class TestClass : TestApp
```

The single colon is just regular inheritance.